# Example of an integer point on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am writing an elementary text on The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm.  I don't have access to a math package.  By way of illustration, I want to provide an integer point on the curve:

$$y^2 = x^3 + 3x + 1$$

It has to be congruent (mod 23) with one of the following points:

$$
4,10 \\
4,13 \\
5,7 \\
5,16 \\
8,10 \\
8,13 \\
11,10 \\
11,13 \\
13,11 \\
13,12 \\
14,2 \\
14,21
$$

Thanks so  much for any help you can offer.

Comment: Why not download a free CAS like GAP, SAGE, Maxima or other to play around with this? Also, this is wonderful with examples and all http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ccs130h/notes/ecdsa-cert.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SAGE, the points $(0,\pm 1)$ are the only integral points on this curve.

Comment: Thanks for the information.